# If $f(nc) \to 0$ for all $c>0$ then prove that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, baire-category

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$. If $f(nc) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$  for all $c>0$ then prove that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

I have solved the problem after extending the function continuously to $\hat{ \Bbb R}=\Bbb R \cup \infty$ which is complete then $nc$ is a subsequence going to $\infty$ and hence $f(x) \to 0$.

I think there might be some problem with this solution. Is there some elementary way(highly relative, so you can give any solution that comes up to your mind first)?

Comment: How do you know you can extend this function continuously to $\hat{\Bbb{R}}$?

Comment: I feel somehow I have to use Baire Category. Is there any other approach more elementary?

Comment: @Ri-Li: One of the proof has a reference to a set of problems by Makarov (there is an English translation by the AMS) that uses just simple properties of the real line.

Comment: Can you send me the link?